# What is the reason of mongod service error?

Tags: mongodb, systemctl

I recently added mongo/mongod to my VPS, and it was working really well.
But today I figured out the mongod service was down, for no apparent reason...
I tried to start it back but I keep getting the following error:

```sh
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-05-23 09:24:29 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 19109 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 19109 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CB359158","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"146A158","s":"_ZN5mongo46_mongoInitializerFunction_ServerLogRedirectionEPNS_18Ini
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CAEBC4B3","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"FCD4B3","s":"_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFN5mongo6StatusEPNS0_18InitializerContextEE
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CCC023D5","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"2D133D5","s":"_ZN5mongo11Initializer19executeInitializersERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx11
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CCC02BE0","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"2D13BE0","s":"_ZN5mongo21runGlobalInitializersEiPKPKcS3_","s+":"440"}
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CAEB8F2F","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"FC9F2F","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"AF"}
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CAE2C149","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"F3D149","s":"main","s+":"9"}
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"7F282FF8BBF7","b":"7F282FF6A000","o":"21BF7","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"E7"}
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local mongod[19109]:   Frame: {"a":"5629CAEB4AFA","b":"5629C9EEF000","o":"FC5AFA","s":"_start","s+":"2A"}
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 09:24:29 localhost.local systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I checked and couldn't find someone with a similar issue. The log file only contains thing of when the db was working.
Do you guys have any idea of what to do?

===========

EDIT: Just found these lines before the server stopped in log file

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-22T15:16:58.136+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-22T15:16:58.143+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"DBException::toString(): FileStreamFailed: Failed to write to interim file buffer for full-time diagnostic data capture: /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp\nActual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)39, mongo::AssertionException>\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-22T15:16:58.360+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31431,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"BACKTRACE: {bt}","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"558729CD2C1A","b":"558726F46000","o":"2D8CC1A","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606","s+":"1EA"},{"a":"558729CD4699","b":"558726F46000","o":"2D8E699","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"},{"a":"558729CD1886","b":"558726F46000","o":"2D8B886","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","s+":"A6"},{"a":"558729E60306","b":"558726F46000","o":"2F1A306","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","s+":"6"},{"a":"558729EF4549","b":"558726F46000","o":"2FAE549","s":"__cxa_call_terminate","s+":"39"},{"a":"558729E5FD25","b":"558726F46000","o":"2F19D25","s":"__gxx_personality_v0","s+":"2C5"},{"a":"7FC384262573","b":"7FC384252000","o":"10573","s":"_Unwind_GetTextRelBase","s+":"1E03"},{"a":"7FC384262AD1","b":"7FC384252000","o":"10AD1","s":"_Unwind_RaiseException","s+":"2B1"},{"a":"558729E60467","b":"558726F46000","o":"2F1A467","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"37"},{"a":"558727E601C2","b":"558726F46000","o":"F1A1C2","s":"_ZN5mongo13error_details23throwExceptionForStatusERKNS_6StatusE","s+":"1B72"},{"a":"558727E7444F","b":"558726F46000","o":"F2E44F","s":"_ZN5mongo21uassertedWithLocationERKNS_6StatusEPKcj","s+":"27B"},{"a":"558727BD64D5","b":"558726F46000","o":"C904D5","s":"_ZN5mongo14FTDCController6doLoopEv.cold.395","s+":"2D"},{"a":"5587283EFE5C","b":"558726F46000","o":"14A9E5C","s":"_ZNSt6thread11_State_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJZN5mongo4stdx6threadC4IZNS3_14FTDCController5startEvEUlvE0_JELi0EEET_DpOT0_EUlvE_EEEEE6_M_runEv","s+":"5C"},{"a":"558729E7BD7F","b":"558726F46000","o":"2F35D7F","s":"execute_native_thread_routine","s+":"F"},{"a":"7FC38403A6DB","b":"7FC384033000","o":"76DB","s":"start_thread","s+":"DB"},{"a":"7FC383D6371F","b":"7FC383C42000","o":"12171F","s":"clone","s+":"3F"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"4.4.6","gitVersion":"72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"4.15.0-122-generic","version":"#124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"558726F46000","elfType":3,"buildId":"9E4C4D3B7
```

Comment: That smacks of permission problems.  Check each file and path mentioned in the conf file to make sure they exist and can be read/written by the service user.

Comment: Just checked and they are all owned or readable/writeable, just found an interesting line in log tho, editing question

Comment: Maybe delete `/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp`  file or even entire `/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/` folder?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did and it didn't help :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out this error was due to no more disk space available. After free-ing some space, I also had to chown a file in `/var/lib/mongodb`, then it worked again!